# Scraable game in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm very new to dictionaries and I'm trying to implement a simple game of scraable in python that returns the score I get for each word I input.
However I`m not to familiar with dictionaries and I want to understand what's wrong with my code.

I've created a dictionary where every letter has its own score.

```
points = {'A':1, 'B':3, 'C':3, 'D':2, 'E':1, 'F':4, 'G':2,
'H':4, 'I':1, 'J':8, 'K':5, 'L':1, 'M':3, 'N':1,
'O':1, 'P':3, 'Q':10, 'R':1, 'S':1, 'T':1, 'U':1,
'V':4, 'W':4, 'X':8, 'Y':4, 'Z':10}

def scraable():
    total_score=0
    word=input('Digit a word\n')
    for i in word:
        total_score=total_score+points[i]
    return total_score
print(scraable())
```

It gives me a key error 'p' and I don`t know what type of error is this

Comment: If your input is in lower case you should convert it to upper case, since that is what your dictionary uses.

Comment: The points dict has only upper case letters so it seems that you would need to change the calculation of the score to: 'total_score=total_score+points[i.upper()]'?

Comment: as @khelwood mentions, it's probably just the fact that your dictionary keys are in upper case but you inputted a lower case. try adding `i.upper()` in `...+points[i]`. Thanks @glhr

Comment: @zero `i.upper()` not `i.lower()`, the keys are in uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most pythonic way would be to use a comprehension and `sum`:

```
points = {'A':1, 'B':3, 'C':3, 'D':2, 'E':1, 'F':4, 'G':2,
'H':4, 'I':1, 'J':8, 'K':5, 'L':1, 'M':3, 'N':1,
'O':1, 'P':3, 'Q':10, 'R':1, 'S':1, 'T':1, 'U':1,
'V':4, 'W':4, 'X':8, 'Y':4, 'Z':10}

def scraable():
    word=input('Digit a word\n')
    return sum(points.get(l.upper(), 0) for l in  word)

print(scraable())
```

We use `dict.get` to avoid error if something is not in the dictionary getting a default value of `0` points for it. 
Also, we use `str.upper` because in the dict all keys are in uppercase, so in case the input is in lowercase it will fail (`"W" != "w"`).

Comment: a simple question.

Comment: Imagine i have the following code  v=[]

def creat_list():
    n=int(input('Number of elements in list\n'))
    for i in range(0,n):
        x=int(input('Digit element\n'))
        v.append(x)
    return v
print(creat_list())  how do i do a list compreension of this.

Comment: `return [int(input("Digit element\n")) for i in range(0, int(input('Number of elements in list\n')))]`

Comment: and in that list comprehension where do you append the elements?

Comment: You are taking n input elements, surrounding the `x for x in xs` expresion by `[]` it creates a list with those elements.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, put your letters in upper case as follow :

```py
for i in word:
  total_score=total_score+points[i.upper()]
```